# Delegate vs Method

Tags: .net, delegates, lambda

Is there any advantige using delegates instead of methods? For example:

```
public void LoginAuthenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
 if (Membership.ValidateUser(lgUserLogin.UserName, lgUserLogin.Password))
     {
       Func<string, string> getDestinationPage = (userLogin) => { //definition };

     e.Authenticated = true;
     lgUserLogin.DestinationPageUrl = getDestinationPage(lgUserLogin.UserName);
  }

else
   {
    Action<string> invalidLogin = (msg) =>
     {
       lgUserLogin.FailureText = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(msg) ? "Invalid login" : msg;
       e.Authenticated = false;
     };

     MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(lgUserLogin.UserName);
      if (user != null)
       {
        if (user.IsLockedOut)
         {
           invalidLogin("User has been blocked");

         }
         else if (!user.IsApproved)
          {
           invalidLogin("User is not activated");
          }
          else
           {  
             invalidLogin(null);  
           }

       }

       else
         {
           invalidLogin(null);
         }
   }
}
```

If I `getDestinationPage` define as 
`private string getDestinationPage(string login){...}` 
and `invalidLogin` as 
`private void invalidLogin(string msg){...}`

does it gives any benefits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case it makes the code cleaner and more readable to use methods. There is no benefit in using delegates like this.

Your code would look like this:

```
private string getDestinationPage(string userLogin)
{
    // definition
}

private void invalidLogin(string msg)
{
    lgUserLogin.FailureText = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(msg)
                              ? "Invalid login"
                              : msg;
}

public void LoginAuthenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    if (Membership.ValidateUser(lgUserLogin.UserName, lgUserLogin.Password))
    {
        e.Authenticated = true;
        lgUserLogin.DestinationPageUrl = getDestinationPage(lgUserLogin.
                                                              UserName);
    }

    else
    {
        e.Authenticated = false;
        MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(lgUserLogin.UserName);
        if (user != null)
        {
            if (user.IsLockedOut)
            {
                invalidLogin("User has been blocked");
            }
            else if (!user.IsApproved)
            {
                invalidLogin("User is not activated");
            }
            else
            {
                invalidLogin(null);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            invalidLogin(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But you are missing the fact that it is not just a function pointer, but in fact a closure with some free variables. You cannot do that with methods alone. You need a classes too.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497801/closures-are-poor-mans-objects-and-vice-versa-what-does-this-mean for an explanation :)

Comment: @leppie: The only variable he uses is `e` as far as I can see. This could easily be passed to the private method. No need for a class in his case. Thanks for the link, but I know about closures and the classes that are created in the background.

Comment: Sure he can do some lambda lifting, but that makes the calls more complicated. Imagine referencing several free variables say 10 of them. No way I will be passing that amount of parameters for every call. You might say use a class then, but then we are back to square 1 (my first comment) :)

Comment: @leppie: My answer specifically states that *in his case* it is better to use methods. I agree, that this depends on how many variables from the surrounding scope you are using in that delegate. BTW: I don't see how lambdas are needed in that case. I will update my answer with a clean example of his code using methods.

Comment: @leppie: In his code, it isn't even necessary to access `e` in the method.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth, do you think your code cleaner and more readable? It's about the same with my code.

Comment: My code is cleaner and more readable, yes. The reason is that the definition of `invalidLogin` and `getDestinationPage` is not cluttered inside the other code.

Answer (score 1):

Lambdas are anonymous methods. You use them mostly in cases where you want to pass a bit of code into a method as a parameter.

For example all LINQ methods work with lambdas because

```
var result = list.Where(x => x % 2 == 0);
```

is much more concise then

```
var result = list.Where(IsEven);

public bool IsEven(int i)
{
    return i%2 == 0;
}
```

An other usage are expression trees.

In your case a normal method is the better choice regarding readability/maintainability.

Comment: Edit your answer please. You missed a bit :)

Comment: ops, sorry :) damn copy&paste errors

Answer (score 1):

You can access (capture) the local variables of the calling function `LoginAuthenticate` from within `getDestinationPage` and `invalidLogin`. `invalidLogin` captures `e`. If you make this a method, you have to pass `e` as an additional parameter.

If you don't need this, it is indeed cleaner to just declare a private method.

Answer (score 1):

Methods are basically "what the object can do". Delegates are the mechanism to decide "what to do" and "do it" in different places. It's like making premature decisions when comparing to if(a) then b(); else c();

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to work with different scenarious where users may be redirected to different destination pages (programatically), and there are several different methods handling this depending on the situation with some conditionals etc., then yes delegates have the advantage as you may change the method to call just by assigning the new method to the delegate instance. Other than that, I don't see any point.